# Camera homography for two different cameras

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, homography

I am trying to perform camera homography between two different cameras. I have the camera extrinsic and intrinsic parameters shared by the factory between the pair of cameras. I apply the camera homography shared on the opencv page ([opencv homography tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html)) and verify the output warped image2 w.r.t image1 and they both are not aligned . I have few questions regarding the same.

1. Can I apply this method to two different cameras as the tutorial mentions for same cameras at two different positions
2. If I cannot used the above method, what changes do I need to make for camera homography to work for two different cameras

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. In the step where you convert your Euclidean Homograpy (H<sub>ab</sub>) to a Projective Homography(H'<sub>ab</sub>):

H'<sub>ab</sub> = KH<sub>ab</sub>K<sup>-1</sup>

Use the intrinsic matrices of each camera instead of the same one on both sides: K<sub>a</sub> and K<sub>b</sub>:

H'<sub>ab</sub> = K<sub>a</sub>H<sub>ab</sub>K<sub>b</sub><sup>-1</sup>